# convert lap times from factor to Time with decimals in R

Tags: r

i have got a set of F1 lap times that in minutes and seconds. the seconds have tenth, hundred and thousands of a second and i need to keep it that way as i am trying to graph this data but R classes it as a factor. i have tried to convert it to numeric(as.numeric) but that does not seem to work.
here is a data sample:

```
DriverId      Q1       Q2       Q3
    1       1:05.585 1:04.772  1:04.293
   20       1:04.655 1:07.354  1:04.123
```

`ggplot`does not let me graph the data properly if it is not in the right format.
i have tried using the `chron` and `POSIXlt` packages with no avail as it seems that they do not support the `mm:ss.000` format
help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strptime`, where `%OS` represents the seconds and their fractional parts. Example:

```
x<-as.factor(c("1:04.293",'1:04.772','1:04.890'))
options(digits.secs=3)
x<- strptime(x, "%M:%OS")
```

Output:

```
"2018-01-13 00:01:04.293 CET" "2018-01-13 00:01:04.772 CET" "2018-01-13 00:01:04.890 CET"
```

Return only minutes and seconds (as character), for example for tick labels in a plot:

```
format(x,"%M:%OS3")
[1] "01:04.293" "01:04.772" "01:04.890"
```

So an example with plotting:

```
plot(x,c(1,2,3),xaxt='n')
at <- axTicks(1)
axis(1, at=at, labels=format(as.POSIXct(at,origin='1970-1-1'),"%M:%OS3"), las=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for that! but, is there a way to have just the time and not the date and the time zone?

Comment: actually that give me the time in this format `"2018-01-13 00:01:26 GMT"`and also gets rid of the decimals?

Comment: Hi Raul, sorry I forgot to add a line to my answer. Also, I updated it now to show a way to return only the minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a `times` class object with `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(df1, key, val, -DriverId) %>%
      mutate(val = chron::times(paste0("00:", val)))
```

In the above, we converted it to 'long' format.  If we don't need to reshape, then

```
df1 %>%
      mutate_at(vars(-DriverId), funs(chron::times(paste0("00:", .))))
#  DriverId       Q1       Q2       Q3
#1        1 00:01:06 00:01:05 00:01:04
#2       20 00:01:05 00:01:07 00:01:04
```